# How to merge two json responses in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two api json response as

```
"aws": [
    {
      "id": "i-0b3db6cb7bebde704",
      "cloudProvider": "aws",
      "type": "t2.micro",
      "placement": {
        "region": "ap-southeast-1",
        "availabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1a"
      },
      "os": {
        "ImageId": "ami-0801a1e12f4a9ccc0",
        "platform": "Linux/UNIX",
        "name": "amzn2-ami-kernel-5.10-hvm-2.0.20220316.0-x86_64-gp2",
        "description": "Amazon Linux 2 Kernel 5.10 AMI 2.0.20220316.0 x86_64 HVM gp2",
        "hypervisor": "xen",
        "architecture": "x86_64"
      }
    }
  ]
```

other one is

```
 "azure": [
    {
      "id": "crawler-rnd",
      "cloudProvider": "azure",
      "name": "crawler-rnd",
      "type": "Standard_E4s_v3",
      "placement": {
        "region": "centralus",
        "resourceGroup": "CRAWLER-RND"
      },
      "os": {
        "platform": "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
        "name": "Windows-10"
      }
    }
  ]
```

I'm using React, Redux. I tried to merge two Json objects, both responses have same property names, I tried several methods like spread operator, Object.assign() but in that case first one is  overwrite by second one,  expected result is given below,:

```
"aws": [
    {
      "id": "i-0b3db6cb7bebde704",
      "cloudProvider": "aws",
      "type": "t2.micro",
      "placement": {
        "region": "ap-southeast-1",
        "availabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1a"
      },
      "os": {
        "ImageId": "ami-0801a1e12f4a9ccc0",
        "platform": "Linux/UNIX",
        "name": "amzn2-ami-kernel-5.10-hvm-2.0.20220316.0-x86_64-gp2",
        "description": "Amazon Linux 2 Kernel 5.10 AMI 2.0.20220316.0 x86_64 HVM gp2",
        "hypervisor": "xen",
        "architecture": "x86_64"
      }
    },
{
      "id": "crawler-rnd",
      "cloudProvider": "azure",
      "name": "crawler-rnd",
      "type": "Standard_E4s_v3",
      "placement": {
        "region": "centralus",
        "resourceGroup": "CRAWLER-RND"
      },
      "os": {
        "platform": "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
        "name": "Windows-10"
      }
    },
    
  ]
```

Comment: The prerequisite for using React is some familiarity with HTML and JS. You don't seem to make make a clear distinction between objects and arrays in JS, which means React code code won't make a lot of sense to you. I advise you go through some of the available resources of learning JavaScript first. While there are plenty of good resources, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) is a good place to start.

Comment: The array you're looking for is `const results = [r1.aws, r2.azure];` You'll then be able to use `results[0]` and `results[1]`. If you want to name the responses for easier access, you could use: `const result = {aws: r1.aws, azure: r2.azure}`. Now you'll be able to access your items at `result.aws` and `result.azure`. This assumes `r1` and `r2` are the responses you showed above.

Answer (score 1):

You can produce the resulting array that you want by `concat`'ing the two arrays together:

```
var result = {
  'aws': response1.aws.concat(response2.azure)
};
```

Comment: I tried this. but didnt work

Comment: Is there some kind of error? Or what is the output from the concat? (How didn't it work?)

Comment: This worked dr. Actually there is a fault with response. So concat worked. Thank you

Comment: @surangi1996 If this answered your question, please accept this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let response1 = {
  "aws": [
    {
      "id": "i-0b3db6cb7bebde704",
      "cloudProvider": "aws",
      "type": "t2.micro",
      "placement": {
        "region": "ap-southeast-1",
        "availabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1a"
      },
      "os": {
        "ImageId": "ami-0801a1e12f4a9ccc0",
        "platform": "Linux/UNIX",
        "name": "amzn2-ami-kernel-5.10-hvm-2.0.20220316.0-x86_64-gp2",
        "description": "Amazon Linux 2 Kernel 5.10 AMI 2.0.20220316.0 x86_64 HVM gp2",
        "hypervisor": "xen",
        "architecture": "x86_64"
      }
    }
  ]
};

let response2 = {
  "azure": [
    {
      "id": "crawler-rnd",
      "cloudProvider": "azure",
      "name": "crawler-rnd",
      "type": "Standard_E4s_v3",
      "placement": {
        "region": "centralus",
        "resourceGroup": "CRAWLER-RND"
      },
      "os": {
        "platform": "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
        "name": "Windows-10"
      }
    }
  ]
};

let structuredResult = {
  'aws': [ ...response1?.aws, ...response2?.azure ]
};

console.log(structuredResult)
```